# React - How to specify an icon in an object as a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-icons

I have an array with objects before, I applied icons from fontAwesome as a value, it looked like this

```
const SideBarColors = [
   {
        IconStyle: {
            Icon: faDotCircle,
        }
   }
]
```

Then in another component I got this icon like this

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={SideBarStyle.Icon} />
```

Now I use a different approach (React Icons), the point is that now I create icons in this way

```
<BsBraces />
```

In this case, I cannot assign this icon inside the object as a value, it gives an error

```
IconStyle: {
    IconTitle: <BsBraces />
}
```

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to :

```
IconStyle: {
    IconTitle: BsBraces
}
```

without the `</>`

Apply it to JSX like:

```
<IconStyles.IconTitle />
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing the file extension from .ts to .tsx? This will allow the JSX.Element (react icons) to be in the file.

Comment: This could be better as a comment